# Include React to existing web page - multiple react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to include React to an web page.  i would like to break up the components into it's own .js files.  i am not having any luck.

My index.html file looks like this.

```
<html>  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src = "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js ">/script>
    <script src = "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js "></script>
    <script src = "https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"> 
    </div>
    <script src="app.js" type="text/babel"> </script>
    <script src="greetings.js" type="text/babel"> </script> 
  </body>
```

My app.js file looks like this.

```
class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return (
           <div>
             <Greetings />
             <h1>Hello World!</h1>
           </div>
             )
          }
      }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

My greetings.js file looks like this

```
class Greetings extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return <h1>Hi</h1>
 }
}
```

So i was expecting "Hi" followed by "Hello world!" but i am getting "Greetings is not defined".

Can you help me?

Comment: If you remove `<Greetings />` from `App`, does "Hello World" show up in a browser inside an h1 tag? That would tell us that you are able to render JSX.

Comment: Yes, it does display "Hello World".

Comment: Great! Are you importing Greetings at the top of app.js?

Comment: no i am not.  How do i do it?  i assume you have to "export class Greetings..." to the greetings.js file but import didn't work.  i had "import {Greetings} from "greetings.js" but the error message said something about require...

Comment: you need the export Greetings and in you app.js import it

Comment: @tiborK  Can you show me the sample code?

Comment: @ThomasDKim check out this short tutorial https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question.   The order which loads the .js files was the problem.
it has to be

```
<script src="greetings.js" type="text/babel"> </script> 
<script src="app.js" type="text/babel"> </script>
```

Then it displayed the web page correctly.