# React added to existing webpage does not render components from multiple files

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add some functionality to my existing website with React. 
I followed [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html). I came to a point where I wanted to separate classes from single `js` file to one for each class.
Then I used

```
import InputField from './InputField';
```

Which gave me this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

When I imported my classes the same way in an example which was created via [this tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html), it worked perfectly.
I also tried with `require()`, but that gave me an error message saying that `require()` is not defined.

So how to divide classes from single file to multiple files on an existing website that has React as an addition? Am I forced to write all code in one file, if I just add React to website? I suspect, that it does not compile as it somehow should. (I am just starting with React)

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56177960/include-react-to-existing-web-page-multiple-react-components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to use native [*ES modules*](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/) or use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) or [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/)